# Black background when resizing GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

While executing a Matlab GUI (designed with GUIDE), if I resize the window and some part goes out of the screen limits, it gets black, except buttons, edit boxes, etc that remain right. So I am looking for any function that refresh the GUI. Could you help me with that?

I would like to include that "refreshing function" in the ResizeFcn.

Thanks.

Comment: This might not answer entirely your question but could you get the screen size (`get(0,'ScreenSize')`)
and prevent the user from moving the window outside of the limits? Or is it really that you want to refresh the GUI?

Comment: `drawnow` is the function that updates a figure window and its children. Here's the help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html

Comment: Moving the window is not a problem, @Benoit_11.
I check the window limits and, after that, I move it back within the screen limits. But the part that was resized outside the screen limits is black.

Comment: @CST-Link, nope, it didn't work. I also used it.

Comment: @YisasL Then is likely a problem of the renderer (maybe solvable in the underlying Java graphics support?) However, I don't understand one thing: *what* exactly gets black? The background of a figure? of an axis? a text edit? etc. Could you make some print-screens before/after, and put them in your post?

Comment: I have same question here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933205/matlab-gui-background-color-changing-to-black-when-using-parallel-computing-mlp